When White plays 1.d4 2.c4 or 1.d4 2.Nf3 3.c4, does White then generally play e4 when he can? Or is it okay to just play the more solid e3?
Is getting Pawns on e4 and d4 only a goal if White starts 1.e4 or also if White starts 1.d4?

I suggest that you browse the questions here tagged with "center", the answer that is always correct is "Depends". For the specific title question, factually 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 will see 4. e4 in 50%, 4. e3 in only 5% (Lichess opening book). And I doubt 4. e3 is "safer" at all! In Kings Indian-ish setups, Black plays e5 anyway, and you practically beg for e4 and the same storm at the White king side that you have in the Kings Indian anyway...
